# User does not have permission to comment on this post

Tags: support, comments

I get this error when I try to comment on a seemingly normal [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375655/1052284) to a seemingly normal question.

Comment: Does this happen everytime you try to comment?  Was it only on this answer?  Is it still happening?  What browser are you using and version?

Comment: Only this answer. Haven't tried other answers on the same question (don't want to bother people with automated emails, and then delete the comment), but commenting in any other question thread works fine.

Comment: I don't know what you did, or what happened, but it works now.

Comment: I did nothing.  Sometimes there are issues when posting a comment, when it happens just try again. :)

Comment: It happens because your cookies have got cleared as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237992/user-does-not-have-permission-to-comment-on-this-post-error)

Comment: In my case I had to relogin again. After that I could comment.